# Entry query returns all fields with NULL

Tags: entry, query

When trying to query a specific single entry in a section I get back a result but all the fields inside that result are nulled.

This

```
{% set kundenmeinungen = craft.entries.section('unterseiten').slug('kundenmeinungen').one() %}

{{ dump(kundenmeinungen) }}
```

returns multiple fields that all look like this even though there is content inside the cms:

```
["seitenContent"]=> NULL
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you call `dump(kundenmeinung.seitenContent)`? Do you have more than one site configured?

Comment: @Johannes you saved me. I got it working by using this:

`{% set kundenmeinungen = craft.entries.section('unterseiten').slug('kundenmeinungen').one() %}

{{ dump(kundenmeinungen.seitenContent.type('textbewertungMitBild').all()) }}`

Comment: Looks like `seitenContent` is not a trivial field type but maybe a matrix field?

Comment: @Johannes yes it was a matrix field. All the other fields were easy to get but the matrix field not. I struggled for hours with this.

Comment: Oh crap, hours? Well, don't hesitate to create questions here. Also, have a look at the Craft Discord server.

Comment: @Johannes ah didn't kniw there's a discord. Yes I spent 2 hours on it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `seitenContent` is a matrix field, here's why it returns a `null` value: If you query for an entry all trivial fields are loaded right away, however non-trivial fields types like matrix, entry, asset and so on are only loaded if they are actually accessed in the Twig template (lazy loading). This is why `{{ dump(kundenmeinungen) }}` shows a `null` value on that field.

PS: If you would eager load that matrix field it would show the actual content in the dump command. To eager load a relational field you would do something like this:

```
{% set kundenmeinungen = craft.entries.section('unterseiten').slug('kundenmeinungen').with(['seitenContent']).one() %}
```

Note that `kundenmeinungen.seitenContent` is an array then. You have to access it like `kundenmeinungen.seitenContent[0]`.